# Using DTE, reading the .NET Standard Project, Configuration Manager Properties Property Value Throws

Tags: c#, envdte, configurationmanager

My project is a VSIX project in Visual Studio 2019.

I'm using the DTE2 to read each build Configuration and then check the value of the NoWarn property.

For a .NET project such as a WPF project, the below code works perfectly.

For a .NET Standard project, it crashes when trying to read the nownarnProperty.Value.

```
foreach (Configuration configuration in project.ConfigurationManager) {
    Properties configurationProperties = configuration.Properties;
    Property nowarnProperty = configurationProperties.Item("NoWarn");
    var value = nowarnProperty.Value;
}
```

The .NET Standard project throws when attempting to read the value:

StackTrace - nowarnProperty.Value 'nowarnProperty.Value' threw an exception of type 'System.Runtime.InteropServices.COMException' object {System.Runtime.InteropServices.COMException}

**Question**

- Does Microsoft have a different method for reading values between
  .NET projects and .NET Standard Projects?
- Is there a special library I have to use to read the above property
  value?

Thank you very much in advance,

Karl

Comment: Did you ever figure this out?  I'm reading a csproj from a VSIX which is .net 4.8.  I'm seeing the same issue reading any of the csproj config properties, all throw System.Runtime.InteropServices.COMException: 'The method or operation is not implemented.'